# Using masksToBounds Makes my UILabel disappear in my custom tableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Background**

Hello, I have a tableView with custom cells as shown in the picture below.

[image]

**Goal**

My goal is to make the green squares circular. I tried doing this with the code below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ColorKeyCell", for: indexPath) as! ColorKeyCell


   cell.colorCircleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.frame.size.width * 0.5)
   cell.colorCircleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
   cell.colorCircleLabel.backgroundColor = colorKey[indexPath.row].color
   cell.exampleLabel.attributedText = colorKey[indexPath.row].basicExample
   cell.explanationLabel.text = colorKey[indexPath.row].explanation

   return cell
}
```

**Issue**

If I comment out the `cell.colorCircleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true` the green box will appear but not circular. If I uncomment it the box disappears completely. Not only that, but if I use `cell.colorCircleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true` on just one of the cells, when populating the tableView, it also makes some of the other cells green boxes disappear also. I did a lot of looking in stack overflow but what unable to come up with a solution. Some said that you needed to call `layoutIfNeeded()` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. The examples were different than my case but I think I tried it correctly and it didn't work.

I was thinking that maybe it either had to do with the horizontal stackView settings, or maybe the hugging or compression priorities on the labels in the stackView, but not really sure. Heres a picture of those just in case.

[image]

Green Box Priorities:
Hugging 251,
Compression 750

Label Priorities:
Hugging 250,
Compression 750

Sound Button Priorities:
Hugging 251,
Compression 750

Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You just set the corner radius like 12 if that green square box have height 24. It makes a circle.

Comment: you can change -> cell.colorCircleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cell.colorCircleLabel.frame.size.height/2

Comment: @Max Dolensky You should handle corner radius related things on your `ColorKeyCell` , Why it's on `cellForRowAt`? And If `colorCircleLabel` have static height means like `24 you should directly give 12 like colorCircleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 12 on your ColorKeyCell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
cell.colorCircleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.frame.size.width * 0.5)
```

To:

```
cell.colorCircleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cell.colorCircleLabel.frame.width/2
```

OR

```
cell.colorCircleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cell.colorCircleLabel.frame.height/2
```

Comment: This should also be there cell.colorCircleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: yeah I kept that in there as well, but still not working

Comment: This works. I must have been tired last night. When I first read this I did not notice that I had the cell.frame.size.width instead of the cell.colorCircleLabel.frame.width. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Great @Max Dolensky

Answer (score 3):

Try using clipsToBounds = true

```
cell.colorCircleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.colorCircleLabel.bounds.size.height  / 2)
cell.clipsToBounds = true
```

This should work.